# Converting TF 2.* keras model to mlmodel for iOS 12 using coremltools 3

Tags: ios, tensorflow, keras, coremltools, mlmodel

I have a `keras` model (`TF 2.*`), and I want to convert it to `mlmodel` with iOS version of 12.

According to `coremltools 4` [release notes](https://coremltools.readme.io/docs/migration-guide-from-coremltools-3-to-4):
"To deploy the Core ML model to a target that is iOS12, macOS 10.13, watchOS 5, tvOS 12, or an older version, use coremltools 3 and tfcoreml 1."

`tfcoreml` is suitable for `TF 1.*` only, so I understand I need to use `coremltools version 3.*`.

I am trying `coremltools version 3.2`, and I would like to use this function `[coremltools.converters.keras.convert][2]`.

I start with a simple try, using fresh venv with `coremltools==3.2`, `tensorflow==2.4.1`, `keras==2.4.3`:

```py
base_model = load_model(keras_model_p)
coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert(model)
```

But I receive the following error:

```
TypeError: Keras layer of type <class 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.Functional'> is not supported.
```

I tried to change the Functional part, changing from:

```py
base_model2 = load_model(keras_model_p)
top_model2 = Sequential()
top_model2.add(Permute((3, 1, 2)))
model2 = Model(inputs=base_model2.input, outputs=top_model2(base_model2.output))
```

to

```py
base_model = load_model(keras_model_p)
model = Sequential()
model.add(base_model)
model.add(Permute((3, 1, 2)))
```

and receive the error:
`TypeError: 'InputLayer' object is not iterable`

The second try is using the first TF 2.* versions: `tensorflow==2.0.0` and `keras==2.3.0`.

I execute the same but receive:

```
ValueError: Keras layer '<class 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.input_layer.InputLayer'>' not supported.
```

How can I solve it?

Thanks